# Array manipulation leads to foreign key removal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord

I want to query the database and store it in an array. I then want to remove one item from the array and give the whole array and pass it to the view.

In this schema every Family has_many users.

```
if user_logged_in
    users = @current_family.users

    users.each do |user|
        if user.id == @current_user.id
            users.delete(user)
        end
    end
    @users = users.map {|user| [user.id, user.name]}
end
```

Whenever I go to delete the user from the array the `family_id` field entry of the user that gets deleted from the array is removed from the database (The user still remains).

How would I structure this to make sure no database entries (foreign keys etc) are touched.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@current_family.users` is not array, it's an ActiveRecord::Relation [delete](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-delete)

So you `delete` a record from the DB, not an element from the array.

Try to narrow the query, something like

```
if user_logged_in
  @users = @current_family.users.where("id != ?", @current_user.id).map {|user| [user.id, user.name]}
end
```

Comment: If you're using Rails 4, you can do: `@current_family.users.where.not(id: @current_user.id)`

Comment: Don't need the `map`:  `@current_family.users.select(:id,:name).where.not(id: @current_user.id)`

Comment: If I wanted to get an array how would I go about it. Would I have to go the other way `User.where(family_id: @current_family.id)`?

Comment: Any `where` method returns relation. If you really need an array, just use `.to_a` - `users = @current_family.users.to_a`